# Different mesh visualization WebGL

Tags: image, webgl, mesh, xtk, paraview

I'm wondering why the mesh in [lesson 10](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/xtk/lessons/tree/gh-pages/10/#run) looks more three-dimensional then mine. My meshes look like they have no surface and no depth. Here is an example picture:

[image]

Any suggestions? I don't see if there is a difference in loading the meshes (xtk's version compared to mine). I think it doesn't depend on the (type of) data because in [ParaView](http://www.paraview.org/) it looks more three-dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your mesh files have no normals.
Paraview will create normals if you don't provide it - not XTK -

You can generate normals for your meshes fairly easily with VTK:
http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyDataNormals.html

1-vtkPolyDataReader
2-vtkPolyDataNormals
3-vtkPolyDataWriter

Maybe you can export the meshes from Paraview or Slicer? Maybe the exported meshes will contain the normals...